# Bootstrap 4 sticky-top margin-top

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have element sidebar and div with class `sticky-top`:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="sticky-top">
           ....
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need pass a margin, when sidebar is sticky, because class sticky-top doesn't have a margin-top.

How I can write margin when sidebar is sticky?

Comment: Possibly dupliate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663517/bootstrap-4-sticky-navbar-with-fixed-margin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - Sticky Navbar with fixed margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663517/bootstrap-4-sticky-navbar-with-fixed-margin)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
.sticky-top { top: 0.5em; }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `top` instead of `margin-top`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="sticky-top" style="top: 30px">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
.sticky-top{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

if it gives you trouble, you can force it with `!important`, like this:

```
.sticky-top{
  margin-top:10px !important;
}
```

Please note that !important should be used only when other solutions are not working.

Hope it help!